# NextJS deploy to a specific URL path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working on my first NextJS application.  When I run "npm run dev" or "npm run start" it deploys my application to

```
http://host:port/
```

When I navigate to a page the url becomes

```
http://host:port/page1
```

I need to have my own specific URL, such as

```
http://host:port/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/
http://host:port/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/page1
```

Furthermore, my app has a lot of  elements to link to other areas of the applications, i need these  to also go to URL with the basePath and not just go to the root path.

I will also be depolying this app to different servers which will have different basePaths, therefore this can not be hardcoded in my app.

*How can I do this?*

With other applications such as react/vue/angular/native JS, I simply build my application and put the build code in a "my-test-application/path-for-my-app" folder on my server.

I tried this with my NextJS application but i got an error that ".next" folder could not be found.

I googled and could find some references to using "assetPrefix" or using "Zones".  However I do not really understand what I am supposed to do.

How do i get my app deployed to specific URL

**Solution 1: Restructure "pages" - Does not enable me to deploy to different servers with different basePaths**

I could create the folder structure inside my "pages" directory and change all my  elements to use this folder structure.

```
|- pages
     |- my-test-application
           |- path-for-my-app
                |- index.js
                |- page1.js


<Link href="/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/page1" >
```

I dislike this solution as the basePath is hardcoded into my application, as to apposed to a deployment setting.

If I wanted to deploy my app on 2 servers with different basePaths (i.e. below) I would have to have 2 versions of the code.

```
http://host:port/my-test-application_1/path-for-my-app/page1
http://host:port/my-test-application_2/diff-path-for-my-app/page1
```

**Updated: I have updated this question on 5th March to include my need for s to work and one solution which I do not like.**

Comment: check https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4998#issuecomment-464345554

Comment: Yes i have read that issue already and still can't understand this

Comment: the path `http://localhost:3000/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/` is not a correct path regarding what you want to achieve.  A production build (deployed) cannot run on loaclhost:3000 either you have a domain or you are doing it wrong. i.g. Your react app should be served under sub directory of your server, `https://example.com/dashboard/page1`

Comment: if you need what you have written just simply prefix all your routes with `my-test-application/path-for-my-app/` and at app start redirect from `/` to `my-test-application/path-for-my-app/` just that, or better define a `basePath` and/or home in package.json

Comment: Sorry I should not have used localhost. It should be something like 'examplehost.com'.  so I am trying to get a URL exactly like you suggested, i.e. Https://example.com/somepath/someotherpath/index

Comment: You mentioned specifying a basepath and/or home in package.json..  how do I do that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution using NGINX to reverse proxy a URL with the base path.

### **Useful links**

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a
- https://www.docker.com/blog/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/

### **Application Changes**

**Dependencies**

- next-images : in order to import static images from "public" when using a reverse proxy
- @zeit/next-css  : in order to use stylesheet files
- as well as usual NextJS dependencies

**next.config.js**

Add a "next.config.js" file at the root of your application so that you can specify the "assetPrefix" and "publicRuntimeConfig.basePath"

- assetPrefix : used by NextJS when accessing components, stylesheets, pages etc
- publicRuntimeConfig.basePath : used in s so specify the prefix to add to the link, used in "src" tags of "" elements when using public images

Example

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

// Enable importing of css stylesheets
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withImages = require('next-images');

/*
 * Gets the BASE_PATH from the command used to start this app.
 * If BASE_PATH is specified but it does not start with a "/" 
 * then add it. 
 */
function getBasePath() {
    var basePath = ''

    if (isProd && process.env.BASE_PATH){
        if (process.env.BASE_PATH.startsWith("/") ){
            basePath = process.env.BASE_PATH;
        } else {
            basePath = "/" + process.env.BASE_PATH;
        }
    } 

    console.log("getBasePath() : isProd = " + isProd);
    console.log("getBasePath() : basePath = " + basePath);

    return basePath
}

module.exports = withCSS(withImages({
    assetPrefix: getBasePath() ,

    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        basePath: getBasePath() ,
    },

}));
```

**Static images**

Use "next-images" in order to import the images and reference the imported object in the 's src tags

Change any references to your static images (those in /public folder) to have the base path prefix. For example my "Footer" component has the following

```
import '../stylesheets/main.css';

import img1 from '../public/image_name1.png'
import img2 from '../public/image_name2.png'

export default class o extends React.Component {

    render(){
        var prefix = publicRuntimeConfig.basePath
        return  (
            <div >
                <a className="icon" href="http://www.image_name.com" >
                    <img src={img1} alt="image_name1"/>
                </a>
                <a className="icon" href="http://www.image_name2.com">
                    <img  src={img1} alt="image_name2"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

*Note: I tried to use the publicRuntimeConfig.basePath as a prefix to the src URL (as below), but this did not work in my deployed environment (see below)*

```
    import getConfig from 'next/config'
    const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
    ...
    ...
    <a className="icon" href="http://www.image_name.com" >
        <img src={`${publicRuntimeConfig.basePath}/image_name1.png`} alt="image_name1"/>
    </a>
```

**Links**

Change your Link's to use the base path prefix, for example in my "Header" component i have the following

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import '../stylesheets/main.css';

import getConfig from 'next/config'
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

const detailId1 = "banana"

const Header = () => (
    <div>
        <div>
            <Link href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.basePath || ''}/`}>
                <a className="linkStyle">Home</a>
            </Link>

            <Link href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.basePath || ''}/about`} >
                <a className="linkStyle">About</a>
            </Link>

            <Link href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.basePath || ''}/details/[id]`} 
                  as= {`${publicRuntimeConfig.basePath || ''}/details/${detailId1}`} >
                <a className="linkStyle">Details Var 1</a>
            </Link>
        </div>
  </div>
);

export default Header;
```

*Note: In the blog https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a, it contains a "Link.tsx" that does the adding of the prefix for you, so you simply use that Link component (import Link from "./Link.tsx";) and not the nextJS version (import Link from 'next/link';).  However, that "Link.tsx" does not work for me when I have variables in my link URLs.*

**Running your nextjs app**

When running your application locally when you do NOT want a base path you can just running

```
npm run dev
```

As no BASE_PATH is specified your application should be accessible from "http://localhost:3000" and your  src values should be "/image_name1.png" and when you hover over your s you will see the link is "http://localhost:3000/pagename"

When you want to run with a base path do the following

```
export BASE_PATH=a/b
npm run dev
```

*Note: for some reason in my environment if i specify "export BASE_PATH=/a/b" (/ at the start of the path) I get a folder directory added to the beginning of the path. Therefore i specify it without the starting / and the code in next.config.js adds the starting / if need be.*

You can not access your app at "http://localhost:3000" as you have the base path/assetPrefix/publicRuntimeConfig.basePath set.  Now you need a reverse proxy.

### **NGINX : Reverse Proxy**

I found the easiest setup was to use a NGINX docker image.  You need to run NGINX with a configuration containing the redirection to your NextJS app.

Create a folder and add in that folder a "default.conf" file. Make sure the path you put in your "location" is the SAME path you specified for BASE_PATH when starting your nextjs app.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /a/b/ {
        proxy_pass http://myhost:3000/;
    }       
}
```

Important Notes:

- you have to have the trailing / on the end of your proxy_pass URL otherwise additional paths are not passed onto your NextJS apoplication
- if you use a variable in the location you must make sure you include passing on the paths

example

```
location ~ /a/b/(.*)$ {  
    set $upstream http://myhost:3000/$1;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

In a command prompt from that directory run a NGINX docker image, telling it to use your config file.

```
docker run --name mynginx1 -v C:/zNGINX/testnginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

- name of the docker container is "mynginx1"
- the v parameter is telling it to copy any files in "C:/zNGINX/testnginx/conf" on your computer to the "/etc/nginx/conf.d" directory in the docker container.  This will copy your "default.conf" to the docker container and NGINX will read that configuration file.
- Note: Make sure you have the "conf.d" in your path for the docker location (":/etc/nginx/conf.d"), blogs I read did not include this part, it only specified ":/etc/nginx/", and without it the image doesn't start.
- the p parameter is telling to run NGINX on port 80

Go to the following URL

```
http://localhost:80/a/b/
```

NGINX will redirect that URL to "http://localhost:3000".  Therefore your application should now be accessible from the URL with the base path.  Clicking on s should work, the link should contain the base path which goes to NGINX which redirects back to the application stripping off the base path leaving any other paths.

### **Real World Server Deployment using Docker**

If you are deploying your application to a server, as apposed to running locally, you can build your application and then copy the relevant files/folders to the server machine. Make sure you have the BASE_PATH set when both building and running your app

```
export BASE_PATH=a/b
npm run build

cp package*.json [server_location]
cp next.config.js [server_location]
cp ./next [server_location]
```

then on that server location run

```
npm install
export BASE_PATH=a/b
npm run start
```

*Note: If you have images in "public" that you reference in your app, use "next-images" and import the image rather than use the publicRuntimeConfig.basePath as a prefix.  When i did the latter the images were not found. See the section about about images for examples.*

Comment: Trailing slash for the proxypas url was what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 21):

In Next.js ≥ [9.5](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#customizable-base-path), you can set a [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) in your `next.config.js`. For example, if you want your entire Next.js app to live at `/docs`, you can use:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/docs'
}
```

Next will will make sure all assets are served from the right place, and it will automatically prefix this base path for all `Link`s in your app, as well as during programmatic navigation using `next/router`. For example,

```
<Link href="/about">
  <a>About Page</a>
</Link>
```

will be transformed to link to `/docs/about`, as will

```js
router.push('/about')
```

This means that you can change `basePath` without changing anything at all in the actual code of your app.

Comment: This seems to also rewrite URL, any idea how to prevent this? For example, when the app is already served at `/docs` and all that we need is ressources/links to be correct (prefixed with `/docs`). What I mean is by default, if you use `basePath`, Next will "blindly" append `/docs` to all URL (which is a problem when your app is already served at `/docs` because the visible URL would be `/docs/docs`).

Comment: @cglacet have you found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem with Next 13 App router

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think we got around the issue by using a sub-domain instead, like `docs.yoursite.com`

Answer (score 5):

To add to the answers here, simply using `basePath` is not enough. `basePath` works very well for automatically pointing links, but it does not do anything to static files served from public directory.

For example you have `public/img/my-img.png` that you referred in your `img` or `Image` element as `<img src="img/my-img.png" />` or `<Image src="/img/my-img.png" />`, you have to change it to `<img src="your-sub-path/img/my-img.png" />` or `<Image src="/your-sub-path/img/my-img.png" />` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom server to create NextJS application work on your specific URL:

See the example here:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express

The key point is to add your specific url as an API, then forward user's request to your specific page you want to serve:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/my-test-application/path-for-my-app', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/index', req.query)
  })

  server.get('/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/page1', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/page1', req.query)
  })

  server.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/posts', { id: req.params.id })
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Comment: I am playing with this now its good until i click on a <Link> element. As the Link just has href="/page1 "the URL is "host:port/page1" and not "host:port/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/page1". Does this mean i have to change all my <Link>s to have the path? If so i might as well just change my code structure and have all my pages under "pages/my-test-application/path-for-my-app"  (I have updated my question with this solution which I dislike).   Also with this express solution, I could not deploy my app on different servers with different basepaths without changing the app code.

Comment: Darryl - I am now using ".env" and "dotenv" to have env vars. I pass this on to webpack so I can use the vars in JS files and set Link tags accordingly.  However when i try and deploy this it fails. I get "Couldn't find a pages directory. Please create one under the project root". I am not sure if this is because of "how" I am moving my files to the server or not. I have opened a separate question for this final issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564471/nextjs-with-express-copying-files-to-server-and-running-npm-run-start-fails

Comment: Darryl RN - I do not understand your update.  Surely the URL to my page will be "http:/host:port/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/index" and that should map to the "pages/index.js" file.   Your updated comment says "you put your pages inside folder"  but what folder is that? It cant be "my-test-application/path-for-my-app" as that will differ per deployment.

Comment: usually, nextjs only look for `pages` folder where you put all of your page files there, but in your case, you put your page files inside `my-test-application/path-for-my-app`. If you want to have it in url and you only have `pages` folder then my first solution was correct.

Comment: Darryl - thank you for that explanation. Its the first of your solution that suits me. Now if only i could get it to work when i copy the ".next" files to my server (see my other question on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564471/nextjs-with-express-copying-files-to-server-and-running-npm-run-start-fails)

Comment: Darryl - i was waiting to resolve the issue with my deployed app before marking the answer as this solution only works in my dev environment not my deployed env

Answer (score 1):

To me, all the solutions mentioned is too much trouble for me, so i rolled the following way.

##### next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/drh',
}
```

##### _app

You can overwrite the `_app.js` file.

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} base="/drh" />
}
```

This way all pages will have a prop `base` hard coded.

```
export default function Index({ base }) {
  return <img src={`${base}/images/hooks-logo.png`}/>
}
```

##### context

if you don't want to push this `base` to all children using a prop, this is the place you can use a `context`. The context provider can be setup in the `_app.js` as well.

seems to me one of a good entry point to nextjs app is `_app.js`, verse a typical react app is `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this, by writing a redirect in next.config.js:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')

module.exports = withImages(withSass({
    cssLoaderOptions: {
      url: false
    },
    //Might need to change it here, before going to the production environment.
    assetPrefix: 'http://localhost:3000',
    postcssLoaderOptions: {
      config: {
        ctx: {
          theme: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_THEME)
        }
      }
    }
}));
```