# NextJS with Express : copying files to server and running "npm run start" fails

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, dotenv

I am creating a NextJS application and I want to copy ONLY the production files to my server and deploy the application. This works perfectly fine when I do NOT use Express, however when i do use Express the app no longer runs on the server as it says it can not find the "pages" directory.

**Project structure**

```
|- .next
|- client
     |- polyfills.js
|- components
     |- CompA.js
     |- CompB.js 
     |- etc
|- node-modules
     |- ...
|- pages
     |- index.js
     |- page1.js
     |- page2.js
     |- etc
|- public
     |- appIcon.png
|- scripts
     |- utils.js
|- stylesheets
     |- main.css
|- next.config.js
|- package-lock.json
|- package.json
```

**My steps**

I develop the application locally and test it my running "npm run dev". When the app is ready to deploy to a server I copy JUST the production files to the server and deploy the application.  It is my understanding that the built application is ALL contained in the ".next" directory, therefore this is the only directory I copy to my server.

Here are my full steps in order to get the application on the server

1. Develop the application locally
2. Test locally using "npm run dev"
3. Test locally using "npm run build" and then "npm run start"
4. Application runs perfectly fine
5. Move the files to the server location and deploy

   1. cp .next ~/myTestFolder
   2. cp package.json ~/myTestFolder
   3. cp package-lock.json ~/myTestFolder
   4. cp next.config.js ~/myTestFolder
   5. cd ~/myTestFolder
   6. npm install
   7. npm run build
   8. npm run start
   9. Application runs perfectly fine

**The process fails when i use Express**

As soon as I use Express, this process no longer works. I need to use express and dotenv so I can have a customizable basePath for my application which can differ on the different servers I deploy my application to (see my other stack overflow question :  [NextJS deploy to a specific URL path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60452054/nextjs-deploy-to-a-specific-url-path))

I did the following:

Install the new dependencies

```
npm install --save express dotenv
```

Create a ".env" file

```
BASE_PATH=/my-test-application/path-for-my-app
```

Update "next.config.js" to read the variables from ".env" and pass to WebPack so it can be used in ".js" files

```
// support getting variables from the server environment
const { parsed: localEnv } = require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    // Stop being being able to access pages without using proper URL
    useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,

    webpack: function(cfg) {
        // pass the environment variables to webpack so JS files can access them
        cfg.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv))    
        ....
    }
    ....
 }
```

Update the scripts in "package.json"

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node ssr-server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node ssr-server.js"
},
```

Create a "ssr-server.js" file to do the routing

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/my-test-application/path-for-my-app', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/index', req.query)
  })

  server.get('/my-test-application/path-for-my-app/page1', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/page1', req.query)
  })

  server.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/posts', { id: req.params.id })
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Update any "Link"s to use this path

```
render(){
    let basePath = process.env.BASE_PATH? process.env.BASE_PATH: "";
    ...
    <Link href={`${basePath}/page1`}> 
    ...
```

I can run the application locally using "npm run dev" and "npm run build"/"npm run start".

However when I copy files to my server location it now fails. I copy all the same files as above with the addition of the 2 new files

- cp ssr-server.js ~/myTestFolder
- cp .env ~/myTestFolder

I run "npm build" OK, but when I run "npm run start" it fails with the following

```
$ npm run start

> React_SSR@1.0.0 start /home/myTestFolder
> node ssr-server.js

/home/myTestFolder/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:3
if(existsSync(_path.default.join(dir,'..','pages'))){throw new Error('> No `pages` directory found. Did you mean to run `next` in the parent (`../`) directory?');}throw new Error("> Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root");}
                                                                                                                                                                   ^
Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
    at findPagesDir (/home/myTestFolder/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:3:170)
    at new DevServer (/home/myTestFolder/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-dev-server.js:1:3830)
    at createServer (/home/myTestFolder/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:105)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myTestFolder/ssr-server.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! React_SSR@1.0.0 start: `node ssr-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the React_SSR@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myTestFolder/.npm/_logs/2020-03-06T10_24_04_105Z-debug.log
```

Any idea what I am missing/doing wrong?

Comment: You need to copy `.next` folder as well, cause this is the output of next

Comment: I need to see your folder structure in your project. The error message was clear `couldn't find pages folder in your root folder`, means you put your `pages` folder somewhere inside `specified name` folder.

Comment: felixmosh - I do copy the ".next" folder, see my step 5.1

Comment: Darryl RN - I have updated the original question to include my project structure

Comment: I read your comment below, can you try to copy pages folder first and see how it runs?

Comment: Darryl - when i copy "pages" as well it complains it can't find a component. Therefore I would have to copy the components folder as well. Therefore i might as well copy the entire project and run the dev, rather than the generated app.  I just don't understand why the introduction of express stops it working

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says:

`Error: > Couldn't find a`pages`directory.`.

you have to `cp pages ~/myTestFolder` as well.

Comment: Surely by copying "pages" to my test folder i am copy the development code, not the built application.  Its my understanding the built application is everything under ".next" and therefore that is all i need to deploy to my actual server.

Comment: Plus copying ".next" is all that was needed when I was not using Express. It fails as soon as Express is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
On this way you don;t need fake copies to make server work properly.
Create and pass args to the next constructor :

```
// Add path module
const path = require('path')

// Init the Next app with args: 
const app = next({ dir: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'yourwww'), dev })
```