# NextJS app deploying using Docker and NGINX so I can have a custom base path

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

I have created an application that is working perfectly locally and now I need to deploy on a server with a custom base path. My app is being deployed to a Docker Container where I have a second Docker Container with NGINX doing reverse proxy.

I have seen lots of blogs/queries/solutions online and after 3 weeks i am still no closer in getting anything to work.  I have tried using "Express" wrapping my app but I encountered blocking issues

- [NextJS deploy to a specific URL path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60452054/nextjs-deploy-to-a-specific-url-path)
- [NextJS with Express : copying files to server and running "npm run start" fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564471/nextjs-with-express-copying-files-to-server-and-running-npm-run-start-fails)

I am using the information in the following blog as to how to use assetPrefix :

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a

**My project structure**

```
|- .next
|- client
     |- polyfills.js
|- components
     |- Link.tsx
     |- etc
|- node-modules
     |- ...
|- pages
     |- index.js
     |- page1.js
     |- page2.js
     |- etc
|- public
     |- appIcon.png
|- scripts
     |- utils.js
|- stylesheets
     |- main.css
|- next.config.js
|- package-lock.json
|- package.json
```

Example of how static images are being used in my app

```
<img className="my-images" src="/appIcon.png" alt="App Icon"/>
```

Example of how style sheet is being used

```
import "../stylesheets/main.css";
```

**"next.config.cs"**

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS();

module.exports = withCSS({
    assetPrefix: process.env.BASE_PATH || '',

    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH || '',
    },

    webpack: function(cfg) {
        const originalEntry = cfg.entry
        cfg.entry = async () => {
            const entries = await originalEntry()
            if (entries['main.js'] &&
                !entries['main.js'].includes('./client/polyfills.js')
            ) {
                entries['main.js'].unshift('./client/polyfills.js')
            }
            return entries
        }
        return cfg
    },
});
```

**"DockerFile"**

```
...    
COPY package*.json ./
...
RUN --mount=type=ssh npm install
...
COPY .next .next/
COPY next.config.js  ./
...
ENV BASE_PATH=a/b 
CMD [ "./node_modules/.bin/next", "start", "-p", "8080"]
```

**my NGINX rule is**

```
location = /a/b/ {
    set $upstream http://mysite:8080/;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
location /a/b/ {  
    set $upstream http://mysite:8080/;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

It is my understanding that these rules means that a url

- http://host/a/b/ will map to /
- http://host/a/b/page1 will map to /page1

**Link.tsx : overwriting default links to have the basePath as the prefix**

```
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from 'next/link'
import { format } from 'url'
import getConfig from 'next/config'

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

const Link: React.FunctionComponent<LinkProps> = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <NextLink
        {...props}
        as={`${publicRuntimeConfig.basePath || ''}${format(props.href)}`}
    >
        {children}
    </NextLink>
)

export default Link
```

Example of how i am using the link

```
import Link from "./Link.tsx";
....
<Link href="/page1">
```

**ISSUE 1 : assets do not appear to be loading**

I can access my app with the following : http://host/a/b/

However NONE of the static files are loaded, i.e. "appIcon.png" is not found neither is the stylesheet "main.css"

**ISSUE 2 : pages other than "index" are not accessible**

When I try and access any other page using the URL it does not work, the index page is always shown

For example

```
"http://host/a/b/page1"
```

should show page1, but it does not. The index page is shown. It is my understanding that the NGINX rules would remove ONLY the /a/b/ part therefore it should call through to

```
"http://host/page1"
```

and show the page1.

*Why is this not working?*

**Can anyone please advise me how to get this all working.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer in this post which has a comprehensive explanation of the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60952373/2663916

A summary is below.

**For Issue 1 : public images**

I used "next-images" package so that in my components i could import the image and reference the imported image.

next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS(withImages({
   ....
}));
```

In my component import the images

```
import img1 from '../public/image_name1.png'
import img2 from '../public/image_name2.png'
```

reference the imported object in the src attribute

```
<img src={img1} alt="image_name1"/>
```

**For Issue 1 : stylesheets**

When i set the assetPrefix in "next.config.js" correctly and had the value set in the environment when i built and run  my application, and have the reverse proxy using this path then the stylesheets are picked up correctly.

*See the linked stackoverflow answer*

**For Issue 2**

This appears to be an NGINX configuration.

When using a variable in the location you have to make sure you pass on the paths 
for example

```
location ~ /a/b/(.*)$ {  
    set $upstream http://myhost:8080/$1;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

or don't use a variable at all

```
location /a/b/ {
    proxy_pass http://myhost:8080/;
}
```