# Deploying NextJs on Azure Linux

Tags: reactjs

I have a sample project assignment to deploy nextjs on Azure using Node.  On my localhost, i run `npm run build` which creates a `.next` folder ready for production on my Azure. On my localhost, when i run `npm run start`, it works fine.

When i deploy `.next` folder to my web app and run the application, it throws the error `404 Not Found`.

I am very new to nextjs. What could i be missing out in my configuration ?

Comment: Sorry if stating the obvious but have already done an npm install to make sure all local node modules are installed?

Comment: @Alex yes, i have that already done :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the entire root folder onto Azure, then on the server you deploy it by typing like how you would do it localhost.

```
npm run build && npm run start
```

.next folder is only for static deployment.

Comment: Does it have to include node_modules folder as well ?

Comment: don't need to, when u type npm on your vm, it will download and install the node_module folders on your vm.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make so much sense to me. If you copy the root folder you would serve not minified and compiled code. Which is not good at all.
Based on Nextjs documentation, in the .next folder there should be everything needed to run the application.

Comment: Also for static website there is the out/ folder, not the .next one.

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta you need to type npm run build on the server to build the files locally. Next doesn't work with just .next folder. If you do static export, then yes, but you need to add the export line in your build script

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial thanks for your answer. It gets me very confuse tho. Reading from the documentation it says it does need to run npm build and then npm start but it says: "next build builds the production application in the .next folder. " https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server.

Comment: Also, as said above, it doesn't make so much sense to me that on production we serve the non bundled code. Reading other issues on SO shows that others manage to deploy with just the .next/ (+ configs files) or at least had my same understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564471/nextjs-with-express-copying-files-to-server-and-running-npm-run-start-fails

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial The documentation around is very blurry, so it might I got it everything wrong. Do you have experience of deploy a Nextjs + Azure app as you describe? Would you be able to show me the file structure + deployment steps? The only good info with this env I've found is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLsx0iraA-Y

Comment: And once again, in this extension for Nextjs/Azure, it describe how to deploy Nexjs app and seems to me that the only folder needed is .next/ https://github.com/MRCollective/nextjs-server-azuresiteextension

Comment: nothing is mentioned in the original question about App Service, it mentioned linux so the answer is based on the assumption it's a VPS. Also the website you link appears to be really outdated. You need custom server to use that.

Comment: ah, i see. I'm not that familiar with all azure ecosystem, I thought was talking about the app service. Which link is outdated? You mean i need custom server to deploy nextjs on Azure App Service?

Comment: are you serverside generated or static? Please check nextjs deployment documentation, you cannot just use .next files.

Comment: really, if you are not running it on a VPS, you are better off deploying it on Vercel.com than Azure. it's free + deployment is hassle free.